# Appendix and alphabetic appendix number problem

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendices

In the following MWE `\appendix` doesn't change the section numbering to `Alph`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*{\appheading}[1][Mathematical Appendix]{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}%
  \chapter{#1}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo}

\appheading
\appendix
\section{Bar} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\appendix` *does* change the chapter numbering style to `\Alph`, but your code does not contain any `\chapter` command after `\appendix`. Insert one and you'll see.

Comment: @Jubobs I want an unnumbered appendix header "Mathematical Appendix" and then alphabetically numbered sections and subsections. So basically the way to go is to change the section counter to use alphabetical numbers?

Comment: Normally, appendices are chapters, not sections. Why not simply use chapters?

Comment: Something like this: `\newcommand*{\appheading}[1][Apéndice Matemático]{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}\chapter{#1}\renewcommand*{\thesection}{M.\arabic{section}}%
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}}`.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for your answer! I ended up doing what I said in my last comment. Should I accept your answer or post my comment as an answer?

Comment: If you answered your question yourself, you should post your own answer and accept it. I don't mind if you upvote my answer, though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand*{\bookappendix}[2]{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}\chapter{#1}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}\renewcommand*{\thesection}{{#2}.\arabic{section}}%
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Faz} 


\bookappendix{Mathematical Appendix}{M}
\section{Bar} 
\subsection{Baz}

\bookappendix{Statistical Appendix}{S}
\section{Par} 
\subsection{Paz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally appendices are chapters, not sections. I wouldn't deviate from that convention, if I were you. If you want an appendix heading, you can use `\appendixpage` from the `appendix` package.

Note: I've used the `onside` option here to get a more compact output (fewer blank pages).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Mathematical Appendix}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\renewcommand\thechapter{M.\arabic{chapter}}

\chapter{Bar} 

\end{document}
```

[image]